Type alias in class implementing pydantic base model
I'm trying to use an encapsulated type alias in a pydantic BaseModel class:
class MyClass(BaseModel):

  Typ: TypeAlias = int
  some_int: Typ = Field(alias="SomeInt")

def print_some_int(some_int: MyClass.Typ):
  print(some_int)

However, when executing this code, pydyntic raises the following exception:

pydantic.errors.PydanticSchemaGenerationError: Unable to generate pydantic-core schema for typing.TypeAlias

When adding a model_config = ConfigDict(arbitrary_types_allowed=True) to MyClass, it works, but I will get an AttributeError for the Typ in the function definition of print_some_int. I could resolve this by removing the type annotation, but that's not what I want. Is there a way to achieve this?
PS: I'm using python3.10

I don't see, what you're trying to achieve here. Maybe you want to try something along class MyClass(BaseModel, Generic[T]): my_type: type[T]; my_value: T?
